# MongoDB Atlas SHARDED vs REPLICASET cluster - differences?

Tags: mongodb-atlas

What are the differences between `SHARDED` and `REPLICASET` cluster types in the terraform provider [cluster types in the terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mongodb/mongodbatlas/latest/docs/resources/advanced_cluster#cluster_type)?
Can I just make a REPLICASET with `num_shards = 3` and it would be identical to SHARDED? And vice-versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Replicaset** is traditional replication between the members of the set.
One is the primary where all data-changing operations are executed.
The rest are secondaries which replicate the operations of the primary and may be used to read data.
If the primary becomes unavailable another member of the replicaset can be promoted to take this role with only data missing if there was a replicationlag.

A **sharded cluster** in mongodb distributes the data between its member.
For example:
ServerA contains all data in range (a-f) for the sharded collection X. (based on the shard key)
Server B contains the data in range (g-i)
Server C contans the data in range (j-p)
[and so on]

Every *Shard* requires its own server/replicaset.
A sharded cluster requires a *mongos* service which will route requests to the correct server.

Sharding is used, when a lot of write/update or a huge amount of read operations are expected for a collection/database.

[MongoDB Documentation about Sharding](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/sharding/#sharded-cluster)
[MongoDB Documentation about Replicasets](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/replication/)

---

Adressing your question about terraform:

[Terraform documentation for num_shards](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mongodb/mongodbatlas/latest/docs/resources/advanced_cluster#cluster_type)

> num_shards -
> (Required) Provide this value if you set a cluster_type of SHARDED or GEOSHARDED. Omit this value if you selected a cluster_type of REPLICASET. This API resource accepts 1 through 50, inclusive. This parameter defaults to 1. If you specify a num_shards value of 1 and a cluster_type of SHARDED, Atlas deploys a single-shard sharded cluster. Don't create a sharded cluster with a single shard for production environments. Single-shard sharded clusters don't provide the same benefits as multi-shard configurations.

So no, the options SHARDED and REPLICASET are not interchangeable.
If you have no requirement which requires sharding, use a replica set.